# Using both Angular Material and Bootstrap css not work?

Tags: css, angular

I want to use in my project both Angular Material & Bootstrap.
Everything works perfect if I use only Angular Material
and have in Angular.json file the following styles:

```
"styles": ["src/theme.scss", "src/styles.css"],
```

If I also install bootstrap@latest and change the style in Angular.json file to:

```
"styles": [
              "src/theme.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

it seems that my app's style "breaks".
Isn't it possible to use Angular material for some features and bootstrap for some others?

Answer (score 0):

**After install @angular/material**
added those files inside styles

```
 "styles": [
          "src/theme.scss",
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "node_modules/@matheo/datepicker/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
        ],
```

Comment: hmm.. the outcome is still the same.. it seems that the padding of the html elements are affected somehow (using both angular and bootstrap in my app :\ )